# Get images for PDFs from URLs

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, ecmascript-8

I Have the below code that gets urls of PDF files, send them to a convert function and returns them as images, is there a way to make this code more readable?

Is there a way to avoid functions chaining?

```
import PDFtoImages from '../PDFtoImages'
    
export async function convertPDF(file, category) {
const images= await PDFtoImages(file.data)
return {
   category: category ? [category] : [],
    images
  }
}
    
export function fetchBlob(url, opts = {}) {
  return fetch(url, opts).then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) return Promise.reject(new Error(res.statusText))
      return res.blob()
    })
}

export async function fetchFilesAsImages(filesUrls) { 
  const pdfAsImages= []
  await Promise.all(
    filesUrls.map(async file=> {
      pdfAsImages.push(
        await convertPDF(
          {data: await fetchBlob(file.url)},
          file.category
        )
      )
    })
  )
  return pdfAsImages
}
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/255024/revisions#rev-arrow-9d653aa9-079f-4790-945a-e05c584c4b5b) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate. I also moved the text from the title into the body as a question- does that look okay?

Comment: Does the code in the code block reflect the actual indentation, or did you just indent the outer most statements (e.g. `import...`, `export....`, `}` so they would be pre-formatted? For more information about code blocks see [the editing help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 2):

The main issue I see with this code is in the `fetchFilesAsImages()` function. You're needlessly building a results array to return at the end of the call `fetchFilesAsImages()`. Why not just take advantage of the fact that `Promise.all()` will already return a list of what each promise resolved to. So, you could instead write `fetchFilesAsImages()` as follows:

```
export async function fetchFilesAsImages(filesUrls) {
  return await Promise.all(
    filesUrls.map(async ({ url, category }) => {
      const data = await fetchBlob(url);
      return await convertPDF({ data }, category);
    })
  );
}
```

One other thing I would suggest is to just use async/await syntax everywhere. Your `fetchBlob()` could look a little cleaner with it:

```
export async function fetchBlob(url, opts = {}) {
  const res = await fetch(url, opts);
  if (!res.ok) throw new Error(res.statusText);
  return res.blob();
}
```